# Some questions about Bluetooth Low energy basic knowledge

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

1. If CONNECTION_REQUEST command not received by peripheral device during connection established procedure, what 
   central and peripheral device will do?
2. Is initiate state a temporary state? Will master transit state from scanning state to initiating state during connection setup?
3. Can BLE device send advertising packet during connection or connection established?
4. How about BLE frequency hopping strategy? Is it similar with BR/EDR?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question number 2 -

A master can connect from Scanning to Initiating state or directly from Initiating state, depends on the nature of the connection. If more information is needed from the Advertiser **prior** to the connection establishment then Scanning mode will be used to gather that information. You can read more in this great book:
"[Inside Bluetooth Low Energy](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=-LMq0NhoEQgC&lpg=PA167&ots=AYpWzlRxWB&dq=scanning%20vs%20initiating%20states&pg=PA168#v=onepage&q&f=false)" by Naresh Gupta.